# Why isn't jQuery getting along with PHP in this situation?

Tags: php, jquery

Okay, so before I ask my question I will explain the flow of things. Form submits data to `add()` method (localhost/share/add) in the `ShareController`, from there it is shipped over to the `ShareModel` method `createShare()` where the magic is *supposed* to happen.

My AJAX code:

```
var formData = $(form).serialize();
var form = $("#add-share");
$(form).submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $(form).attr('action'),
    data: formData,
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(data) {
        if(data == 1) {
            alert("Woohoo!");
        } else {
            alert("Womp!");
        }
        console.log(data);
    }
})
});
```

ShareController add() method:

```
public function add() {
    ShareModel::createShare(Request::post('share_title'));
    Redirect::to('share');
}
```

ShareModel createShare() method:

```
    public static function createShare($share_title) {

    if(strlen($share_title) > 55) {
        Session::add('feedback_negative', Text::get('FEEDBACK_SHARE_TITLE_LONG'));
        return false;
    }

    if(strlen($share_title) < 5 || empty($share_title)) {
        Session::add('feedback_negative', Text::get('FEEDBACK_SHARE_TITLE_SHORT'));
        return false;
    }

    $data[] = 0;
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

The issue:

Ajax is returning everything fine "Womp!" when I have the backend PHP validation commented out, however when I have it implemented the AJAX does not work, and the backend validation does not take over. Anyone have an ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Can you copy the body of your XHR request? or a `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: You may need to switch the first two lines of your ajax code for your form data to have values.

Comment: `if(data == 1)`. But `data` is a json object..?

Comment: `if(data == 1)`  Please show the code where you think you are setting the response to "1".  None of what you are currently showing would do that.

Comment: I had to comment out the AJAX request, if i just submit the form without touching any other code I get "[0]"

Comment: @PatrickQ I'm setting the data to 0. If I set it to "1" I get the appropriate response you'd expect.  i.e "Woohoo". However if I re-implement the contents of the if statements the response is no more.

Comment: `$data[] = 0;` is not setting the data to `0`, it will add an array element `0` to your JSON data array. If you just want to return 1 or 0 from PHP to your AJAX response you can simple use `echo '1';` (or `0`), without `json_encode`. It's probably better to return JSOn like `{ success: true  }` instead of just 0 or 1 though.

Comment: @xander I was confused about that, I have however implemented your suggestion. :)